# why script take too time in IE 11?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-11

In my asp.net application,Debug with IE11 take too time for response.(min 2 minute).IE say "localhost not responding dut to a long running script.".How can i check which script taking too time?

[This is running script list in vs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVkSR.png)

[This is IE profiler order by inclusive time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN9dT.png)

Comment: what is "querySelectorAll" function?

Comment: This function contain in jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

Comment: @Nirman [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is a standard (Selector API Level 1) method for returning elements that match a CSS selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable to browser Link Option.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnKrn.png)

The cause of the problem is that the Browser Link feature requires dynamic compression to be disabled. The dynamicCompressionBeforeCache attribute allows IIS to dynamically compress the response when a request is made for the first time and queues the content for compression. When this attribute is enabled, a page loads faster, whereas if it is disabled, it causes additional CPU consumption and increases the page load.More Information Here=>[Troubleshooting issue related to browser link feature](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T102322)